# I get invalid index descriptor when using ancient FoxPro 2.6 tables

Tags: delphi, foxpro, bde

I'm connecting to old FoxPro 2.6 tables in Delphi 2007.
I've installed the BDE and I put a TTable on the form.

**One table doesn't work**
Set the `databasename` to `c:\datadir` and
The tablename to `contacts.dbf`.

When I set active to true, I get

> invalid index descriptor.

**Another table works fine**
I have another table called `article.dbf` that loads fine, and in the original program everything works fine as well.

**Here's what I've tried**
I've already re-indexed everything in the original program, but that makes no difference.
In fact the diagnostic from Foxpro says that everything is OK.
I don't really care about any indexes because there are not that many records in the table.
I've tried setting the `indexfile` property, but that doesn't help.

How do I get Delphi to just connect to the table and stop complaining about indexes?

Comment: If you don't need to write back to the file, you can remove the 'cdx' flag on a copy of the .dbf and open that one. Byte 28 -> not 0x01 ([refer here](http://www.dbf2002.com/dbf-file-format.html)).

Answer (score 3):

Probably your contacts.dbf table contains expression index that cannot be evaluated by BDE. Here is an explanation I have found [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/12537)

> Question: What types of FoxPro indexes
>   are not supported by the BDE? When
>   trying to open some tables, I get an
>   "Invalid Index Descriptor" error.
>
> Answer: This error occurs when the
>   production index (.CDX) associated the
>   table has an index tag which has an
>   expression which the BDE cannot
>   evaluate. The solution is to delete
>   the tag using FoxPro create an
>   eqivalent index that the BDE can
>   understand.
>
> The following conditions are not
>   supported by the BDE and will cause
>   "Invalid Index Descriptor" error.
>
> DTOC(, 1) format not supported; Use
>   DTOC(). ALLTRIM function not
>   supported; Use LTRIM(RTRIM(Field)).

Answer (score 2):

Here's code that Sertac described that will remove the auto-open CDX flag from the header. **Make a copy** of the dataabase first, of course.

```
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
  ByteRead: Byte;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create("YourFile.dbf", fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareDenyNone);
  try
    // Byte offset 28 has a value of 0x01 if a structural (auto-open) index exists,
    // or 0x00 if no such index exists. If the value is not set, we do nothing.
    Stream.Position := 28;
    Stream.Read(ByteRead, SizeOf(ByteRead));
    if ByteRead = 1 then
    begin
      ByteRead := 0;
      Stream.Position := 28;
      Stream.Write(ByteRead, SizeOf(Byte));
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```